# How to minimise CPU usage doing JSON to Apex conversion across 70,000 lines?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

Please help me finalizing Apex Wrapper Classes for parsing a very large JSON. JSON shown below comprises of product configuration data from ERP. (This JSON is usually 60k to 70k lines; it is scaled down here to make the point).

**Problem Summary** : 
I have tried using JSON Parser . This approach consumes a lot of CPU time. 
I don't have control on changing the JSON structure at source however, if I could, I'd ask for changing children{} (Object) to children[] (array). Please notice that children can have children too.
Services like JSON2APex or AdminBooster create a ton of classes.
**JSON (60K to 70K lines)**

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": "Engine Options",
      "dataType": "A",
      "decimal": 0,
      "children": {
        "1.0": {
          "id": "CASE OPTIONS",
          "control": "COMB",
          "children": {
            "1.0": {
              "id": "CAR",
              "control": ""
            },
            "2.0": {
              "id": "CFO",
              "control": ""
            }
          },
          "changed": false,
          "selection": {
            "dataType": "A",
            "description": ""
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "Carburettor Options",
      "dataType": "A",
      "decimal": 0,
      "children": {
        "1.0": {
          "id": "CASE OPTIONS",
          "control": "COMB",
          "children": {
            "1.0": {
              "id": "CAR",
              "control": ""
            },
            "2.0": {
              "id": "CFO",
              "control": ""
            }
          },
          "changed": false,
          "selection": {
            "dataType": "A",
            "description": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "infoMsgs": [],
  "line": 2,
  "unitPrice": 1,
  "adviceMsgs": [],
  "errorMsgs": [
    "[0]{PR.BASE.LCK::PRICE NOT FOUND - ENTER PRICE OR CONTACT PRICING TEAM   71000.952 }"
  ]
}
```

**More info** : 
1) This data comes via GET / REST callouts will be used to show product line configuration to customers.
2) I'll eventually need to send this data to Javascript to populate picklists in Lightning.

Comment: Run JSON parsing logic in a Async Apex like @future or batch class. So it will reduce CPU overhead.